# How to schedule multiple notifications from an activity?

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager

Can someone please tell me what changes i'd have to make to the code below to schedule multiple notifications(at different timings).

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

This is the part of my Android Manifest file where i added the class that extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
        </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher"/>
</application>
```

At present only my last scheduled notification appears.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for my dumb question. I was not clear on what the parameters were for PendingIntent.getBroadcast().
All I had to do was creating unique PendingIntents by changing the 2nd parameter.